# When do you add connections in the MySql-workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, connection, mysql-workbench

I'm new to mysql so I'm trying to unterstand the basics.

I started with connecting python with mysql and it all worked fine. Then I noticed, that you could add a **new connection on the MySql Workbench**, so I tried it out as a test. Now I had the **"local instance MySql"** and the **"test"** connection on the main page of the MySql mainpage.

When I later created a database and a table in python, it added both, in each connection.
So i had now a database and a table in the **"local instance MySql"** and the same database and a table in the **"test"** connection.

At this point i don't see when you would add connections.

Comment: that is quite confusin. workbench is like your python program and every connection made woorks only in mysql workbench. So you see i am confused, test and local instance MySql connect to the same mysql server like your python program ?

Comment: Lets say you are supporting multiple versions of mysql with multiple versions of your db , not so odd if you have dev,test,staging multiple connections or a PC/server each.?